# for loop function executed onClick

Tags: html, loops, for-loop, onclick

i want to update multiple iframes with one button click, and I dont want to have to edit the src title a bunch of times... I tried this... didnt work...

```
<script>
function setURL(url){
<%
Dim t
For i = 0 to 1
document.getElementById('frame' & t).src = url & "0" & t & ".html";
Next
>%  
}
<script>

<button type="button" class="siteButton0" onclick="setURL('about')">About</button>
```

essentialy I have frame0 and frame1 and want to replace url with about00.html and about01.html respectively.

first post... go easy folks...

Comment: What server side language are you using? I'd recommend adding that tag so people familiar with the language might offer advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new here and so am I to ASP or whatever that is, but I guess, I know what you're trying to do. ASP is server-side and it's supposed to print the JS to be executed in the browser - not in the server. Please try:

```
<%
Dim t
For i = 0 to 1
%>
document.getElementById('frame' & <%=t%>).src = url & "0" & <%=t%> & ".html";
<%
Next
%>
```

Comment: i havent been able to get back to this yet, but thank you so much, it looks right, strange syntax though...

Comment: True. The alternative is printing the js-line, but that would mean escaping some characters, which I just prefer not to do.